# Subscribing without creating an account

Tags: magento2

if someone registers or i create an account for the customer, he gets an e-mail notification where to put it!
I can't find this setting
Or is that set in the code?
i use magento 2.3.5

Comment: Hi, Do you want an admin setting for Customer Email while registering?

Comment: no, the customer does receive a notification e-mail after registration.
where can I set what is in the mail?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update the content of customer registration email. Here are two steps to find which email template are being used in your Magento and how to update it.

**Step 1:**
To find the email template used for the Welcome Email in Magento 2 when a customer creates a new account, follow these steps:

1. Log in to the Magento Admin Panel.
2. Go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
3. In the left-side menu, navigate to Customers > Customer Configuration.
4. Scroll down to the "Create New Account Options" section.
5. Look for the "Email Templates" option and find the template for "Welcome Email".

This will give you the name of the email template used for the Welcome Email in Magento 2 when a customer creates a new account.

**Step 2:**
To update the Welcome Email in Magento 2 from the admin panel, follow these steps:

1. Log in to the Magento Admin Panel.
2. Go to Marketing > Communications > Email Templates.
3. Search template for the Welcome Email (which we find in first step) and click on "Edit Template". **Note:** *If you don't find any welcome email template here then you need to create new one. please follow steps mentioned in **Step 3***
4. Modify the content of the template as per your requirements.
5. Click on "Save Template" to save the changes.

Note: It is recommended to make a backup of the original template before making any modifications.

---

**Step 3:**
To add a new template for the Welcome Email in Magento 2 from the admin panel, follow these steps:

1. Log in to the Magento Admin Panel.
2. Go to Marketing > Communications > Email Templates.
3. Click on the "Add New Template" button.
4. Load Default Template by selecting **New Account** from dropdown and click on Load Template.
5. Click on "Save Template" to save the changes.

Once you have created the new template, you can set it as the default welcome email template (newly created) by following the mentioned steps in above **Step 1**

Cheers!

Comment: That's exactly where my problem is, I also thought that it had to be there! "Email Templates" but unfortunately there is no template for registering!
https://prnt.sc/n-rdu5arLOEo

Comment: I can see that "Neues Konto(Standard)" is the your template configured currently which is default in Magento and coming from file system. If you want to edit the template then just create new template as per "Step 3" in my answer and then "untick" Systemwert Verwenden and select newly created template to reflect changes.